# Which mathematical function looks like this?

Tags: math, calculus

Symmetrical along the diagonal, but not approaching any asymptotes:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/2vDLran.png]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.  You would be better suited to ask this question on https://math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

In the positives, `e^x-1` has this behavior, and in the negatives, by inversion, `-ln(1-x)`.

At the origin, the first and second derivatives coincide.

[image]